# Using proxy for custom docker based GitHub action on a selfhosted runner

Tags: docker, github-actions

We have a selfhosted github server with selfhosted runner and the whole infrastructure uses JFrog as Docker registry.

Now we also have  custom GitHub actions that are based on images within the private JFrog registry. The problem is that the action will be build before the workflow even run and the JFrog denies access to the image.

How can I authenticate the github action runner to the docker registry before it starts the workflow? Or what would be the right way to do it?

Only way I can imagine is rewrite the action to a composite action and do the stuff within the container directly but it feels wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job and Service containers in GitHub Actions allow you to containerize your CI environment and make databases, caches, or other services available to your tests. Previously those containers had to come from a public container registry which limited the usefulness for some customers. Additionally, we had numerous requests from the GitHub community forums for private registry support.

Here’s an example of using private images from Docker Hub and GitHub Container Registry:

```
jobs:
  build:
    container:
      image: octocat/ci-image:latest
      credentials:
        username: mona
        password: ${{ secrets.docker_hub_password}}
    services:
      db:
        image:  ghcr.io/octocat/testdb:latest
        credentials:
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ghcr_password }}
```

https://github.blog/changelog/2020-09-24-github-actions-private-registry-support-for-job-and-service-containers/

Comment: So I can't use the custom action anymore. I have to build it into a full fledged docker image and use it this way?

Comment: AH, yeah, for a container based action, only public container registries are supported.